# Sql way to update a value using the row before

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following table:

I want the initial_balance for the second row (`transaction_id = 124`) to be the `final_balance` of the first row (`transaction_id = 123`), but I just can't.

I tried using this code:

```
UPDATE transactions
SET initial_balance = (SELECT final_balance 
                       FROM transactions 
                       WHERE transaction_type = 1)
WHERE transaction_id = 124
```

Which when selected just the part in parentheses does return the value from the table, but the whole code when running results in an error:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'transactions' for update in FROM clause

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stupid limitation in MySQL. You cannot use the table you are updating or deleting from directly, but must select from it indirectly. That means we have to replace `FROM transactions` by a ridiculous `FROM (select * from transactions) t`.

Then, there is also a semantical error in your query, because you forgot to tell the DBMS that you want ID 123.

So either:

```
UPDATE transactions
SET initial_balance = (SELECT final_balance 
                       FROM (select * from transactions) t
                       WHERE transaction_type = 1
                       AND id = 123)
WHERE transaction_id = 124;
```

or correlated:

```
UPDATE transactions
SET initial_balance = (SELECT t.final_balance 
                       FROM (select * from transactions) t
                       WHERE t.transaction_type = 1
                       AND t.id = transactions.id - 1)
WHERE transaction_id = 124;
```